# Взаимодействие нескольких select

Tags: html, jquery

Как заставить один select закрыться, если в другом выбрано определённое значение.

Например:

```html
 
<span>Вы женаты?</span>
<select>
<option>Да</option>
<option>Нет</option>
</select>

<span>Вы ищите девушку?</span>
<select>
<option>Да</option>
<option>Нет</option>
</select>
```

Как сделать, что если в первом select выбран пункт "да", то второй получает пустое значение value и закрывается от редактирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще всего завернуть в блок элементы, что хотите скрыть:

```
<span>Вы женаты?</span>
<select id="isMarried">
    <option></option>
    <option value="1">Да</option>
    <option value="0">Нет</option>
</select>
<div id="isLooking">
    <span >Вы ищите девушку?</span>
    <select>
        <option value="1">Да</option>
        <option value="0">Нет</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Проверяете опцию "женат". Если да, то скрываете ненужный селект. На случай, если будет ошибочно выбрана опция "женат", а потом изменена, else вернет скрытый объект в видимое состояние.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {    
        $('#isMarried').change(function () {
            var selectedOption = $('#isMarried option:selected');
            if (selectedOption.val() == '1'){
                $('#isLooking').hide();
            } else  $('#isLooking').show();
        });
            // Если нужно получить переменные и где-то потом использовать:
            var married = $('#isMarried option:selected').val();
            var looking;
            if (married == 0) {
                looking = 1
            } else looking = 0;
    });    
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Например так)

```js
function my_func(){
 var res=document.getElementById('select1').value;
 if(res!=='0'){document.getElementById('select2').removeAttribute('disabled').removeAttribute('disabled');}
 else{document.getElementById('select2').setAttribute('disabled','disabled',true);}
}//end function...
```

```html
<span>Вы женаты?</span>
<select id="select1"  name="select1" onchange="my_func()">
<option>Ваш выбор</option>
<option value="0">Да</option>
<option>Нет</option>
</select>

<span>Вы ищите девушку?</span>
<select id="select2" name="select2" >
<option>Да</option>
<option>Нет</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё приходит с опытом :3

```js
$('#marriage select').on('change', function(){
  $('#search').toggleClass('--disabled', $(this).val() === 'Да'); // Если выбран вариант "Да", то выставляем блоку класс `--disabled`, в ином случае удаляем.
  if($(this).val() === 'Да') // Если же выбран "Да"..
    $('#search select option').eq(0).prop('selected', true); // В "отключаемом" селекторе берём первый элемент "по умолчанию - false" и даём ему атрибут selected.
});
```

```css
#search.--disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="marriage">
  <span>Вы женаты?</span>
  <select name="marriage">
    <option value="false">Выберите результат</option>
    <option>Да</option>
    <option>Нет</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="search">
  <span>Вы ищите девушку?</span>
  <select name="search">
    <option value="false">Выберите результат</option>
    <option>Да</option>
    <option>Нет</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

> это ответ на свой старый пост, аккутанее